# Need help creating an exercise/solution template

Tags: xsim

I am trying a create a simple and minimal layout for a collection of problems my department uses for a high school mathematics contest. I would like the exercises to simply be numbered consecutively, the exercise numbers printed in bold font and followed by a period and a space. I created a `xsim.style.math-contest.code.tex` file shown below.

```
\xsimstyle{math-contest}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{prob}
{\par\noindent\textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}. }}{}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{soln}
{\par\noindent\textbf{Solution: }}{}
```

The output generated by the sample LaTeX below, generated the bold period and space, but is missing the exercise numbers. What does the `xsim.*.tex` content need to declare the counter property for the exercises?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[use-files]{xsim}

\loadxsimstyle{math-contest}
\xsimsetup{%
    path = exercises,
    print-collection/print = both,
    exercise/template = prob,
    solution/template = soln
}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{shortanswer}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{team}
\DeclareExerciseTagging{mode}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{shortanswer}
\xsimsetup{mode=short}
\begin{exercise}
What is $1 + 1$?
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
The answer is $2$.
\end{solution}
\collectexercisesstop{shortanswer}
%
\collectexercises{team}
\xsimsetup{mode=team}
\begin{exercise}
What is $1 + 2 + \cdots + 100$?
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
The answer is $5050$.
\end{solution}
\collectexercisesstop{team}

\section*{Short Answer Exercises}

\printcollection{shortanswer}

\section*{Team Exercises}

\printcollection{team}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If the answer was helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: A]

Use this setup

```
\xsimsetup{%
    collect, % added <<<<<<<<<<
    path = exercises,
    print-collection/print = both,
    exercise/template = prob,
    solution/template = soln
}
```

If you are curious, look at the `.xsim` file with a text editor, using `collect` or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and it works! Perhaps this was added to xsim version 0.20c. It is described in the xsim manual, but its purpose in numbering exercises was not clear to me.